# slider does not work twice on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slide

I'm trying to use the same slide twice on the page but does not work. Only works first. Images do not appear in the second slider when I duplicate the html.

Code

```
$(function(){
        $('#slides2').slides2({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 0,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What slider are you using? `.slides2` looks strange to me.

Comment: yes! Works only on the first slide

Comment: Mhh is that an answer to my question? It looks like you try to increment the "slides" function to "slides2" which will of course not work. Maybe the slider is called slides2 but that's the reason I'm asking for the slider you are using.

Comment: I'm using two codes to different pages just by changing class names, ID and CSS.

Both for Home and Home Affairs.

I think there may be a problem of nomenclature

Answer (score 0):

The function `slides2` does not exist in the code of the slider plugin you've posted. Just use `slides` again. On another element with a different ID of course. Thats what I was trying to find out with my comment to your question.

For the first you may use:

```
 $('#slides1').slides({
```

Then for the second use:

```
$('#slides2').slides({
```

Comment: Is that the first or second slider? If your are using `#slider1` and `#slider2` in javascript the first slider must start with `<div id="slider1">` and the second with `<div id="slider2">`.